# MySQL on Sublime text 3 on MAcOS

Tags: mysql, macos, sublimetext3, macos-catalina, sublime-build

I'm writing this command

```
"cmd": ["/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql", "-u", "root", "-e", "source $file", "-t"],
    "selector": "source.sql"
```

on Sublime Text 3 to create a new build system for MySQL on my MAcOS Catalina . But it shows the error::
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Please help me with the same

Comment: Does that exact same command work when run in Terminal?

Comment: No  , although I never tried it  , I've always tried it in sublime text

Comment: Well, I would verify it works there first...